# Hard to find book in number theory– Proceedings of conference in Budapest 1987

Tags: nt.number-theory, paper-request

I'm looking for a copy of this book, which is hard to find:

Number theory. Vol. I.
Elementary and analytic. Papers from the conference held in Budapest, July 20–25, 1987. Edited by K. Győry and G. Halász. Colloquia Mathematica Societatis János Bolyai, 51. North-Holland Publishing Co., Amsterdam, 1990. 573 pp. ISBN: 0-444-70346-2

Anyone know where/how to get access?

Comment: Interlibrary loan?

Comment: our library has it, I might scan a few pages if that is all you need; if you would need the full volume you probably want to borrow it yourself from a library; here is where you can find libraries that have it: https://www.worldcat.org/title/number-theory-vol-1-elementary-and-analytic/oclc/839690367&referer=brief_results

Comment: WorldCat search: https://www.worldcat.org/search?q=bn:0444704760+OR+bn:9638022426+OR+bn:0444703462+OR+bn:9638022450 that returns more records

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions and @Carlo the offer. It looks like Gerry's is the way to go which may take some time due to the pandemic.